# TypeError: element.change is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive

My directive looks like this

```
'use strict';  
angular.module('WebApp').directive('someAppFormat', function ($filter, $timeout) {   
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    //Functions            
        element.change(function () {
            //Do Something...
        });
```

I get the following error:

```
angular.js:12722 TypeError: element.change is not a function
at link (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/AngularJs/Directives/someAppDirectives.js?v17.0.2.0.2:61:17)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:9039:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:8533:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:7929:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:7932:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:7932:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:7809:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:7947:16)
at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:8560:18)
at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost/webApp/Scripts/angular.js:27921:15) <input type="text"  
class="someAppValidatorSpan ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="someAppPercentInput" 
name="someAppPer{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="someAppVm.someAppPercentages[$index]" 
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 20000, 'blur': 0 } }" 
someApp-format="">
```

I believe the `element.change` (function) is legitimately a function and that my issue is elsewhere.  Could I be missing some dependency?

Comment: AngularJS element does not have a `change` function. -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element Don't just belive, read. -> `element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have included jQuery.js in page, and included it before angular.js,  `angular.element` does not have a `change()` method

Use `bind()` or in newer versions `on()`

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        element.bind('change', function () {
            //Do Something...
        });
        // or 
        element.on('change', function () {
            //Do Something...
        });


}
```

Or you can use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, this was the answer.  jQuery was on the page but it was towards the bottom.  Once I pushed it into the head it worked.
I will however alter the function to not use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't just belive, read about it. =)

[AngularJS element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) does not have a change function &  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches

#### You can use the jqLite Methode [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  to make this work. In that way you dont need to mix jQuery with AngularJS.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    element.on('change', function () {
        //all your goodness
    });
}
```

Comment: I now think that the page shouldn't use jQuery, but I wonder now should I use jqLite's on() or if I should try and use ng-change instead.

Comment: @Sniipe You could also achieve that by using `$watch`. There are a lot of different ways to create a solution. It's on you to check your requirements and discover the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive `link` function you are passing in the element as "element", but the in the function you are attempting to reference "elm" which not defined from what I can see. Angular element does not have a change function as others have stated, but you need to reference "element", instead of "elm".

```
'use strict';  
angular.module('WebApp').directive('someAppFormat', function ($filter, $timeout) {   
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    //Functions            
        element.on('change', function () {
            //Do Something...
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that was a typo.  I've edited the OP.